# how many content type fields can I have on a drupal site?

Tags: entities

I have a Drupal site for tracking equipment. I have a bunch of content types that are basically questionnaire forms that are related to the equipment. I need to associate those with specific equipment nodes.

ex. equipment node "1500" has 6 forms that each have numerous fields that need to show up under it when you view the full node. I've done this with entity views attach and it works fine. But one of these forms has about 85 fields in it. Most of these fields are checkboxes/radio buttons. Some of the other forms have 40-50 fields.

I recently noticed my site's performance slowing to a crawl after adding these fields to one of the content types and I'm worried that there are too many fields. I can't find any info on how many fields I can use though. Does Drupal limit the number of fields? Or is there some other limitation that could cause a problem?

RJ

BTW: I was going to use webform, but I can't access the fields in views with that (don't think so, anyway)

Answer (score 2):

In Views, take a look at the SQL that it is generating in the preview of the view.  If you see tons and tons of JOINs, one for each field, that is most probably the cause of the slowdown.  What Drupal does is create a table for each field that is shared between content types and that means Views has to join everything back together again based upon the nid.  So, if this is happening, you might be able to improve performance by having each of these fields unique to an individual content type.  In that case, just as long as they are single value fields, they will just be another column in the database table defining the content type and can be grabbed all at once.